# How to enable an existing mousewheel-driven value-change on just focused number-type input-elements?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, user-input, event-listener

I have a working script but I don't know how to use `addEventlistener` instead of `onfocus` & `onmousewheel`. And how to apply it to many elements?

```js
const input = document.getElementsByClassName("change-onscroll")[0];
input.value = input.min ? input.min : 0;
input.onfocus = () => {
    input.onmousewheel = (e) => {
        if (deltaY > 0 && +input.value <= +input.min) return;
        e.deltaY < 0 ? input.value++ : input.value--;
    };
};
```

```html
<input type="number" name="num" class="change-onscroll" min="0" />
```

Comment: You mean that you need to the events `onfocus` and `onmousewheel` with `addEventListener` for all the inputs with class name as `change-onscroll` ?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes exactly. But I'm not sure which one is better. It seemed to me that the option with `addEventlistener` is a more correct way.

Comment: Check this example https://codepen.io/manmur/pen/XWYzwVg

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Yes it works! But only fix `onfocus` → `focus` & `onmousewheel` → `mousewheel`

Comment: My bad, sorry for not updating that. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the OP wants to enable the scroll behavior for just focused input elements the OP needs to **explicitly** do both **registering** such a handling on any such element's `'focus'` or `'focusin'` event and **deregistering** the handling again on any such element's `'blur'` or `'focusout'` event

```js
function handleNumberTypeMouseScroll(evt) {
  const { currentTarget: input, deltaY } = evt;
  const minValue = parseInt(input.min, 10);
  
  if (deltaY > 0 && input.value <= minValue) return;
  deltaY < 0 ? input.value++ : input.value--;
}

function deregisterMousewheelHandling({ currentTarget }) {
  currentTarget
    .removeEventListener('mousewheel', handleNumberTypeMouseScroll);
}
function registerMousewheelHandling({ currentTarget }) {
  currentTarget
    .addEventListener('mousewheel', handleNumberTypeMouseScroll);
}
document
  .querySelectorAll('.change-on-focused-scroll')
  .forEach(elmNode => {
    elmNode.addEventListener('blur', deregisterMousewheelHandling);
    elmNode.addEventListener('focus', registerMousewheelHandling);
  });
```

```html
<input type="number" name="num" class="change-on-focused-scroll" min="0" value="0" />
<input type="number" name="num" class="change-on-focused-scroll" min="5" value="5" />
<input type="number" name="num" class="change-on-focused-scroll" min="20" value="20" />
```

Comment: Can we use `for...of` instead of `forEach` for more compact way? Like this https://codepen.io/redboo/pen/GRGObyZ

Comment: @redboo ... have a look at the edited example code; it's compact enough now in my opinion.

Comment: I found [this article](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/) which says that the performance of the `for...of` loop is much better.

Comment: @redboo 1st ... the OP can do whatever the OP wants with the above provided example code; 2nd ... choosing `for ... of` does not change the actual solution to the OP's problem of adding/removing eventlisteners on focus/blur; 3rd ... what the OP reads about loop performance is totally irrelevant for e.g. iterating nodelists like with the above examples.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake on this line:
`if (deltaY > input.min && input.value <= input.min) return;` should be replaced with: `if (deltaY > 0 && input.value <= input.min) return;` And I'm having trouble comparing those values, so they must be numbers: `if (deltaY > 0 && +input.value <= +input.min) return;`

Comment: @redboo ... all this requested additional changes can be easily managed by the OP her/himself since the above example code exclusively uses the OP's own provided change behavior. Again, the core problems ask by the OP have been solved.

Comment: Very useful.  Thank you a lot. I'm still learning how to use it.